# How do I send a DateTime or some sort of timestamp from PHP to Java using Hessian binary remoting protocol?

Tags: java, php, datetime, calendar, hessian

There is a Java service that I need to invoke from PHP that looks something like this:

```
getProductsForMode(java.util.Calendar date, int modeId)
```

I'm having trouble mapping my PHP date class to the java.util.Calendar class. I've tried a couple different approaches, all to no avail:

Approach #1 (wrapping DateTime object in a CalendarHandle that gets mapped to Java's CalendarHandle):

```
class CalendarHandle
{
  public $type;
  public $date;

  function __construct($date=null)
  {
    $this->date = $date;
  }
}

$this->hessianClient = new HessianClient(_HESSIAN_ENDPOINT, $hessianOptions);
$config = &HessianConfig::globalConfig();
$config->typeMap->mapRemoteType('com.caucho.hessian.io.CalendarHandle', 'CalendarHandle');

$time = new CalendarHandle(new DateTime($dateEvaluated));
$products = $this->hessianClient->getProductsForMode($time, 1234);
```

Error:

> [06-Jul-2011 11:16:52] PHP Fatal
>   error:  Uncaught exception 'HttpError'
>   with message 'HttpError: Malformed
>   HTTP header' in
>   /Users/jordanb/Sites/proposal-framework/trunk/plugins/srHessianClientPlugin/hessianphp/Http.php:265

Approach #2: 
Mapping DateTime to java.util.Calendar

```
$this->hessianClient = new HessianClient(_HESSIAN_ENDPOINT, $hessianOptions);
$config = &HessianConfig::globalConfig();
$config->typeMap->mapRemoteType('java.util.Calendar', 'DateTime');

$time = new DateTime($dateEvaluated);
$products = $this->hessianClient->getProductsForMode($time, 1234);
```

Error:

> [06-Jul-2011 11:28:50] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'HessianError' with message 'Hessian Parser, Malformed reply: expected r' in /Users/jordanb/Sites/proposal-framework/trunk/plugins/srHessianClientPlugin/hessianphp/Protocol.php:350

Has anyone had success sending a DateTime or some sort of timestamp from PHP to Java using Hessian? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be practical to just use the php time() function (which returns an int and send this as a long to Java? In Java you could just pass the long to new Date(long Date).

Comment: Although not ideal, this is probably the best solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use unix timestamp. That's the best bet.

**PHP:**

```
$ts = time();
```

Pass `$ts` to java in someway.

**Java:**

```
long ts = getTimeFromPhp();
Date dt = new Date(ts);
```

Or you can use Calendar:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(ts);
```